# is Lebesgue measure continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

Is Lebesgue measure continuous? Can someone prove it or attach a link to the proof?

I am trying to prove the existence of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ that simultaneously divides 3 compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ into two peices of the same measure.

Comment: What does it mean for a measure to be continuous?

Comment: I assume you mean "subsets" rather than "subgroups".

Comment: FWIW this is the [ham sandwich theorem/problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem)

Comment: You will find what you are looking for here (at least your first question): http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/continuity-of-measures In general, every measure is continuous.

Comment: @LordSoth That is continuous from above and below. But, like Chris Eagle, I don't know what mean for measure to be continuous.

Comment: It looks really like he is asking about whether slight variations of the "plane cut" implicitly yield slight changes in the area on each side of the plane, given how he wants to use it. This is different from the kind of continuity that @LordSoth suggested, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to mathematically formulate this expression is that if $X\subset \mathbb R^3$ has finite Lebesgue measure, define the function on $\mathbb R^3\times S^2$ as:

$$f(u,v) =\mu(\{x\in X: (x-u)\cdot v>0\})$$

Then $f$ is continuous.

It is true, but requires some care to prove. It's a little easier to do with $X$ bounded, since the slight variations in $u,v$ would be of finite measure in a bounded region, so we can easily intuitively make the difference small.

That would suffice for your question since your elements are compact, and hence bounded.